# Redirect to action is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have a table with anchor tag in a column. when user clicks on the link, My action method in controller redirect to another method after doing some update logic. Redirect to another action method then after, is not working in my case?

my View :

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Emended</legend>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>


            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerEmneedOrderedProduct.FirstOrDefault().Prd_Qnty)
            </th>

        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.CustomerEmneedOrderedProduct)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Prd_Qnty)
                    <br />
                    @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "updateOrderedProdStatuCd", new { orderProductId = item.OrderProductId, OrderedProdStatuCd = 2 })
                </td>


            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</fieldset>
```

My Controller :

```
    public class SellerOrderDetailsController : Controller
    {

          public ActionResult OrderDetails([Bind(Prefix = "id")] int? orderId)
          {

          }

         public ActionResult updateOrderedProdStatuCd(int orderProductId, int OrderedProdStatuCd)
         {
                    try
                    {
                        // Updating few stuffs
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("OrderDetails"); //this is not working 
                }
           }
   }
```

Comment: may be control is going in catch block

Comment: @EhsanSajjad nope its not. It would have given me exception in that case.

Comment: what is the controller name and action name in which redirection is needed

Comment: "Not working" can mean a lot of things. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint in the other action and see if gets hit?

Comment: Yes @MarcelN. break point was not hitting

Comment: @Tobias I have edited my post. Please let me know if its understandable

Comment: @Sanju Rao you have redundant bracket after `return RedirectToAction()` and this example works for me, please, provide your routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because you're not passing orderId to OrderDetails action. The action doesn't match method's signature.

Try something like

```
return RedirectToAction("OrderDetails ", new { orderId = 123 });
```

Comment: even if you do not pass parameter (in this case), it has to work, I think something wrong with routes

Comment: @gisek yes that is working now. But my input parameter is null able I never thought It will matters if dont send the aparameter. anyways thank you very much

Comment: @SanjuRao It would work If you made it optional (add '=null'): public ActionResult OrderDetails([Bind(Prefix = "id")] int? orderId = null)